# Brew installing wrong dependencies

Tags: python, macos, gtk, homebrew, pygtk

I'm trying to install [gtk-mac-integration](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8f9f63ec007ffc768b42ef65a72bb14c276ab8a8/Formula/gtk-mac-integration.rb) which, as far as I understand, doesn't depend on python3 (python2 should be enough), but nevertheless brew keeps insisting on installing python3. I don't want to install python3, so unless I'm wrongly understanding the formula of `gtk-mac-integration`, python2 should be more than enough.

Why is brew trying to install python3?

How can I `brew install gtk-mac-integration` without python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk-mac-integration` doesn’t directly depend on `python3`, but one of its dependencies do.

If you run `brew deps --tree gtk-mac-integration`, you’ll get something like this (truncated):

```
gtk-mac-integration (required dependencies)
...
└── gtk+3
    ...
    ├── libepoxy
    │   ...
    │   ├── meson
    │   │   ├── :python3
    │   │   ...
    ... ...
```

`gtk-mac-integration` thus depends on `gtk+3`, which itself depends on `libepoxy`, which depends on `meson`, which needs `python3`.

Running `brew info` on these formulae doesn’t give show any option that’d allow us to avoid installing `python3`. You thus can’t install `gtk-mac-integration` without `python3`.

Edit: `gtk+3` is a recommended dependency; meaning you can build without it if you don’t need it:

```
brew install gtk-mac-integration --without-gtk+3
```

Comment: I manually installed all the (not optional) dependencies of `gtk-mac-integration` and then ran `brew install --ignore-dependencies gtk-mac-integration`. This seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Yes, of course you can ignore dependencies; but there’re probably a reason why python3 isn’t optional.

Comment: gtk+3 is optional, so any dependencies dragged by that should be optional, I assume.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way I can skip the optional deps when installing something via brew?

Comment: optional deps are skipped by default; recommended ones can be skipped using `--without-<formula>`. There’s no global option to skip *all* recommended dependencies.